# Why ping -f command needs sudo privileges?

Tags: networking, ping

When i tried to use `ping -f ipaddress` command in Ubuntu for testing my system , It fails with a message :

```
 ping: cannot flood; minimal interval, allowed for user, is 200ms
```

When i type man ping and see -f option , it state

```
Only the super-user may use this option with zero interval.
```

Why does it need that privilege   ?

Comment: If you have multiple users, think how they will be affected by the extra network traffic. Combine the zero interval with the option to increase the packet-size and it could easily become a problem for administrators. I think you can still use flood if you specify an interval e.g. `ping -f -i 1 192.168.1.1`

Answer (score 7):

from `man ping`

> -f
>   Flood ping. For  every  ECHO_REQUEST  sent  a  period  ``.''
>   is
>                 printed,  while  for  ever  ECHO_REPLY  received  a backspace is
>                 printed.  This provides a rapid display of how many packets  are
>                 being  dropped.   If  interval is not given, it sets interval to
>                 zero and outputs packets as fast as they come back or  one  hun‐
>                 dred  times  per second, whichever is more.  Only the super-user
>                 may use this option with zero interval.

It's obvious clear that the it's forbidden for lowering the network traffic and thus get lowering the threat of DDOS due to large replies for every arrived packet.

Comment: i have already read these lines ,  i know what it makes already , windows permit it with a normal user , that's what i want to know , as your answer windows doesn't know its consequences !

Comment: It's the truth buddy!

Comment: I'd like a source on Windows allowing it, or even having a zero interval flood option...

Comment: @nux, windows does not even support anything close to it.  It can't send more than one packet before it either gets the reply, or times out, and even if you set the timeout to 1 ms ( it errors with 0 ), it still seems to enforce a 1 second minimum before sending the next packet.

Comment: This is only a constraint in software, correct? There is nothing stopping you from recompiling ping without this check and being able to ping flood without root, right?

Answer (score 2):

It is because only super user can specify interval less than 0.2 seconds. And -f is like very very little interval.

P.S. Since commit https://github.com/iputils/iputils/commit/0ccdbb9937a90f4c765fe9ab94d1441dd8680f45 it is now 0.002 seconds. So yeah, that is just a fake protection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in comparing it with the Windows `ping`, because they basically came from  two different origins.

Long ago when nets were congested easily, this was used to *prevent* users from casually running the command and making the net useless. You can see the source code of original `traceroute` command, which says something like

> This command must be run by root or be setuid (I suggest you don't make it setuid -- casual use could result in a lot of unnecessary traffic on our poor, congested nets).

So even till now, this is more like a *reminder* or *preventive measure*, than a *security feature*

Quoting the commit message of https://github.com/iputils/iputils/commit/0ccdbb9937a90f4c765fe9ab94d1441dd8680f45

> NOTE: we keep minimal limit just to make sure people don't
> *accidentally* DoS themselves. It's not that much about security
> (there are other tools to allow DoS if user *wants*).